# AngularJS ui-select, how do I initialize multiselect values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-ui

**Solution:**

Figured it out myself: The whole proble is no problem any longer after applying [this fix](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/256) and doing my custom build of the ui-select. I hope this is going to get into the official master branch some time soon!

**Problem**

How do I initialize a select with multiple values? I'm trying this but it doesn't show the selected items in the selection.

First I thought it has something do to with the data that I'm getting async via HTTP get but not even the "static" plunker example I've made to show the problem works for me.

I think my issue is that the data comes from two different sources so the index and by this references between the two arrays don't match. The list of categories is fetched with a service and the selected categories come from another service that are returned together with the data set that is attached to them. And in another select it would be pretty impractical to load all 45k users just to pick the selected ones from that huge list.

So how could I make my existing selection data appear in the ui-select?

[Plunker link.](http://plnkr.co/edit/95wvJb)

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <label>Assigned Categories</label>
        <ui-select
            multiple
            ng-model="categories.selected"
            on-select="selectCategory($item, $model)"
            on-remove="deselectCategory($item, $model)">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Category...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices
                repeat="category in categories.categories track by category.id">
            {{category.name}}
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
        <pre>{{categories | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [
  'ui.select'
]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.categories = {
            selected: [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Foo"
        }
            ],
            categories: [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Foo 1"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Bar 2"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "FooBar 3"
        }
            ]
        };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to "initialize" the `select` or `ui-select`, or any other `ng-model`-type input is by setting the ViewModel variable that goes into the `ng-model` to whatever the selected value or object (as is in this case) you want.

You attempted to do that in your example, but since you are selecting an object, your VM should have referred to the same object (by reference). Your error was that you instead created a different object with the same content.

So, `$scope.categores.selected` should be an array (since it's `multiple`) of the actual objects:

```
$scope.categories = {
   categories: [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Foo 1"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Bar 2"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "FooBar 3"
        }
    ]
};

$scope.categories.selected = [$scope.categories.categories[0]];
```

Comment: So in short you're telling me to pass the index integer into that array instead of the whole object? Well, this causes me a few other problems then. Is there a way I can track the selection other than by it's array index?

Comment: No, I'm telling you to pass the object by reference; i.e. the object itself. The selection would be the actual object - not an array index

Comment: My issue is that the data comes from two different sources so the index and by this reference as you suggest won't match. The list of categories is fetched with a service and the selected categories come from another service that are returned together with the data set that is attached to them. And in another select it would be pretty impractical to load all 45k users just to pick the selected ones from that huge list.

Comment: This https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/256 describes my issue pretty well and according to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/404 this is still not working.

Comment: I'm not understanding your issue. `ng-model` at all times refers to the actual selection - whether set by controller or by `ui-select`. If your selected records come from a different place, then find which actual objects they refer to in the data set you received from the server and set the `selected` array to these objects. If you don't want to select objects, then select `id`s instead

Comment: My code is completely correct, well except the track by which I've changed now. Read the two links from my previous comment. Especially the PR #256. This fixes my issue. It is a problem of ui-select. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/256#issuecomment-58621992 for another description of the problem, it is the same as mine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I understood what you are trying to do. I suppose it would be helpful to match based on property and not object equality. But this is the way Angular works right now (with `<select>`) and my guess is that `ui-select` mimicked this behavior - so, I'm not sure if they PR would be accepted. If this works for you, that's fine, but like I said, I don't understand why the current-Angular-way would not work, even if you had 45k records. There is no need to retrieve them all.